# Can't get DELETE function to work

Tags: php

Ok, to start...I have a page that will display thumbnail images from my database. 
I want the user to be able to choose an image gallery from a dropdown menu and then the images will be displayed below it, and only the images that are in that gallery will show. I have all of that part working fine, the only issue I have now, is that when I select the picture (via the checkbox below it) and click delete, the DELETE[] function doesn't work...In fact the 'if statement' that has the unlink() function will not even run. I'm missing something here.  I'm using a switch statement to cycle through the option menu. Is it the switch statement that would be causing the issue? I have all the case options and default setup, just not displayed here.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks. I accept all criticism for my code as well.(sql injection and sorts will be handled later) I'm far from pro.  :)

```
FORM
<form action="delete_pics.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="gallerySelection" class="btnExample">
<option value="" class="btnExample">Select A Gallery</option>
<option value="mainGallery" class="btnExample">Main Gallery</option>
<option value="theBikes" class="btnExample">The Bikes</option>
<option value="thePits" class="btnExample">The Pits</option>
<option value="theAction" class="btnExample">The Action</option>
<option value="theBuilds" class="btnExample">The Builds</option>
</select>
</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type='submit' name='next' value='Show Selection' class='btnExample'>
</form>
```

Then here is the Switch statement with the code in it:

```
if(isset($_POST['next']))
   {
   if(isset($_POST['gallerySelection']))
      {
      $selection = $_POST['gallerySelection'];
      }

     switch($selection)
      {
        case "theBikes":    
         {      
           echo"<h4>The Bikes</h4><p><form action='delete_pics.php' method='POST'>";
           $pics = mysql_query("SELECT p_id, theBikes, theBikes_thumb, descr FROM gallery WHERE theBikes        !='' ORDER by p_id DESC");
   if(@mysql_num_rows($pics) >0)
         {
           echo"<table border='0'>";
           $count=0;
             while($row3=mysql_fetch_array($pics)){

            if(isset($_POST['delete'])) /////////////This is where the failed code starts
             {  
                $delete = $_POST['delete'];
                   foreach($delete as $deleted)
                       {
                          $pics_delete = mysql_query("SELECT p_id, theBikes, theBikes_thumb, descr FROM gallery WHERE    p_id=$deleted");
                          $row4=mysql_fetch_row($pics_delete);
                          unlink($row4[0]);
                          unlink($row4[1]);
                          mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallery WHERE p_id=$deleted");
                          printf("<script>location.href='picture_delete.php'</script>");
                        }
              }     ////////////////////////////////////This is where the failed code ends
          else
              {
                 $delete = array();
              }
          if($count==0)
              {
                 echo"<tr><td align='center' width='150'>";
              }
          else
              {
                 echo"<td align='center' width='150'>";
              }
       echo"<div><img src='$row3[theBikes_thumb]' style='border:0px;' width='60' height='75'>   <p>$row3[descr]</div>";
       echo "<input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='{$row3['p_id']}'>"; //////////This is the checkbox to check the picture to be deleted

     if($count==5)
        {
           echo"</td></tr>";
           $count=0;
        }
    else
        {
           echo"<td>";
           $count++;
        }
  }  /////////////End of whle loop
       $cells_left = 5 - $count;
    if( $cells_left > 0 ) 
        {
           $i = 0;
              while( $i <= $cells_left ) 
                 {
                    echo '<td></td>';
                    $i++;
                 }
                    echo '</tr>';
         }
               echo '</table>';
        } 
    else
        {
           echo "No images in the database.";
        }

echo"<div><input type='submit' name='submit' value='DELETE PICTURE' class='btnExample'>

</form>
</div>
";
break;
}
```

Thank you for any and all help!
Have a great day.  :)

Comment: Give it some formatting, can't really read you code.

Comment: you're not doing an error checking on your mysql delete.  Show what's happening in the results of mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallery WHERE p_id=$deleted");

Comment: Also, what's the opening brace for after "case "theBikes":"?  It doesn't seem needed

Comment: Try your query `SELECT p_id, theBikes, theBikes_thumb, descr FROM gallery WHERE p_id=$deleted"` with single quotes around the variable. You should not be using mysql_* functions, as they are deprecated and unsafe. Consider switching to PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deletion form (line 12 of the PHP code) is not sending the 'next' input field. The POST request transfers only this array when no pictures are selected:

```
Array ( [submit] => DELETE PICTURE )
```

Should be:

```
Array ( [gallerySelection] => theBikes [next] => Show Selection [submit] => DELETE PICTURE )
```

Therefore the deletion form never enters your initial IF statement, and ignores the deletion request.

Here's a recommendation: Move the entire deletion process out of the switch case, and add a token check to prevent form jacking. Ideally the process of image deletion should occur immediately following your form processing check (IF statement looking for declaration of $_POST['next']). Also adding the hidden input field for $_POST['next'].

**Example**

```
if (isset ( $_POST['next'] )) { // Your current code for deletion doesn't make it past this check.

    // Check if deletion has been requested
    if (isset ( $_POST['delete'] )) {
        // Deletion process

    }

    if (isset ( $_POST['gallerySelection'] )) {
        $selection = $_POST['gallerySelection'];
    }

    switch ($selection) {
        // Fill in the blanks ...
    }
}
```

Edit: Your example was also missing two closure brackets or "}}".

Comment: Addendum: Information regarding form security & tokens can be found on [phpsec.org](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Baldvin, that was the issue. I just had to remove the entire -if(isset($_POST['delete']))- statement from the while loop and place it before  if(isset($_POST['next'])), works great. (spent 3 days trying to figure that out) haha. much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome @Stuckfornow, glad to be of assistance.